# How to justify one part of a line left and the other on the right hand side

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

I was wondering if it was possible to have two sections of text, on the same line be both left justified and right justified.

For example doing this:

```
{\itshape{\begin{flushleft}I'm on the left\end{flushleft}\begin{flushright}I'm on the right\end{flushright}}
```

Ends up looking like this:

```
I'm on the left
                                                                                  I'm on the right
```

How can I make it look like this?:

```
I'm on the left                                                                   I'm on the right
```

Comment: Just use `\itshape{I'm on the left \hfill I'm on the right}`

Comment: Or use `minipage`s if you need more than that.

Comment: @Guido Unfortunately that did not work :/ it didn't change anything. I just found something and edited it to work though, I'll update the question now.

Comment: Perhaps the use of `paracols` package does help

Comment: I'm surprised that Guido's suggestion does not work for you. This, for example, works as you wish: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}The left \hfill The right\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up solving my problem :)

```
\newcommand{\restitle}[2]{%
  \par\medskip\noindent
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\itshape\normalsize{#1}}%
  \makebox[\textwidth][r]{\itshape\normalsize{#2}}}
```

Usage: `\restitle{I'm on the left}{I'm on the right}`

Output: `I'm on the left                                                   I'm on the right`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a stretched box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\newcommand{\restitle}[2]{%
  \begin{flushleft}% makes for vertical spacing and kills indent
  \makebox[\textwidth][s]{#1\hfil#2}%
  \end{flushleft}
}

\begin{document}

\restitle{I'm on the left}{I'm on the right}

\restitle{Again left}{Again right}

\end{document}
```

[image]